# Not getting the page i want in jsp. Only getting the url which is in action of jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, tomcat6

I have to show a page coded in index.jsp and in this page i have used the onload submit

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myfunc () {
    var frm = document.getElementById("my_form");
    frm.submit();
    }
    window.onload = myfunc;
</script>
<form id="my_form" action="tempmonitor" method="post">
```

the above is my jsp code and i have printed hello on this page. But when i hit the URL localhost:8090/tempmonitoringsystem/index.jsp. It shows index.jsp for nanosec den went away to the folowing URL localhost:8090/tempmonitoringsystem/tempmonitor and i don't know where it is redirecting to. I am Attaching my servlet code as well as xml code.

TempMonitorServlet.java

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
    System.out.println("hello world");
    String path = "E:\\"; 

      String files;
      File folder = new File(path);
      File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles(); 

      for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) 
      {      
          if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) 
          {
              files = listOfFiles[i].getName();

              if (files.endsWith(".txt") || files.endsWith(".TXT"))
              {
                  System.out.println(files);
                  ReadingFromFile read_file = new ReadingFromFile();

                  String last_line_from_file = read_file.read(files) ;
                  System.out.println("\n"+last_line_from_file);
                  if(last_line_from_file != null)
                  {

                      drawImage(req,resp ,last_line_from_file,files) ;
                  }
              }
          }
      }
}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
<display-name>ZigbeeRest</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
```

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>tempmonitor</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>tempmonitor.TempMonitorServlet

</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>com.restful.Zigbee.services.ZigbeeApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>tempmonitor</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/tempmonitor</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Hi Tarun, you do have a window.onload to call your form submit right? The form's "action" attribute must be set to the servlet which it is redirecting to.

Comment: ya if you will see in the web.xml i have done mapping for the appropriate servlet TempMonitorServlet is my servlet name in which all things are happening.

Comment: Please, edit the name of the question as is, it is senseless.

Answer (score 0):

Your servlet is not sending any response, which your form expects to receive for its request.  You need to be "printing" something to your `HttpServletResponse resp`.  In other words,

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

out.write("hello world");

// loop over your files,
out.write(file);
```

whatever you write to the PrintWriter will get sent back to the client.

I'm assuming that this is what you mean by `System.out.println`, and that you are not trying to print stuff into a log file or something like that.

Comment: i am using system.out.println() just for debugging purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems that when you call index.jsp the page is loaded. When the page is loaded the javascript will trigger the submit of your form. Since you have the form action set to "tempmonitor" the page will be send to /tempmonitoringsystem/tempmonitor.

I'm not sure if "/tempmonitoringsystem" is your webapp context or that you are deploying in the root context of your application container. If so /tempmonitor would not match as servlet.

In your doPost method you also do not write to the output stream.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out ya tempmonitoringsystem is my webapp name. I am writing system.out.println() because i was checking whether it is entering in dopost or not. I am just using it for debugging purpose thats all.